# How can I transmit the actual name of the variable in R given this code?

Tags: r

I have the following code

```
f0 <- function(param0) {
  f1(param0)
}
f1 <- function(param1) {
  f2(substitute(param1))
}

f2 <- function(param2) {
  print(deparse(param2))
}

hello <- 5
f0(hello)
```

I do not have control to f1 and f2 (hence, I can't modify them).
I do have control over f0.

This code prints "param0", but I want it to print "hello", that is, to invoke f1 from f0 "as if" f0 named parameter (param0) is not there.

I tried various combinations of substitute and eval, but I got nowhere.

Comment: `f0 <- \(x) {do.call(f1, list(substitute(x)))}`

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen works... but why?

Comment: "why" is beyond my ability to explain I'm afraid, hopefully the bigger brains will be along to help us both!

Comment: from the help for `do.call` : "The behavior of some functions, such as `substitute`, will not be the same for functions evaluated using `do.call` as if they were evaluated from the interpreter. The precise semantics are currently undefined and subject to change."

Comment: I was intrigued by `why` and had you marked as the 'bigger brain'.

Comment: @Chris sorry to disappoint

Answer (score -4):

Try this one.

```
f0 <- function(param0) {
  f1(eval(substitute(param0)))
}

f1 <- function(param1) {
  f2(substitute(param1))
}

f2 <- function(param2) {
  print(deparse(param2))
}

hello <- 5
f0(hello)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did YOU 'try this one' before posting? because it doesn't work to OPs specification.

Comment: @PYGURUDEV please read Stack Overflow's policy on AI-generated answers here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1